# How to update a series value from another series value in highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

Hi everyone I'm trying to update the last point of my actual series to match it with the last point of my planned series. Please see:  jsfiddle.net/Beatles1990/mhzucv9k/2/

What I wanted to do is that if it is the last point of my series (in the actual), that last point must match the value of the last point of my planned series. Can you help me?

Comment: Please check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wg281cn3/ is it an expected output?

Comment: Hi Sebastien, thank you for responding help. In this chart:  jsfiddle.net/Beatles1990/mhzucv9k/2/   What I wanted to do was, if it is the last point of the actual series, the y value of that last point must be the same to the y value of the last point of the planned series. the only update to do  is the y value.. no change in the x value.

Comment: Beatles1990, Thanks for the clarification! Consider this demo then: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cvxna0je/

Comment: Thank so much Sebastian. This is the exactly what I was trying to figure out.